# Office apps issue with SharePoint 2013 on-premise

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, office-web-apps, office-2016

We have office 2016 installed in one of the server recently.

When opening a document from the site (SharePoint 2013 onpremise), Word 2016 opens the document in read-only mode (as expected), but when I click the Edit document button in Word 2016 the following pop up appears:

> there is a newer version of this document on the server. would you
>   rather work with that one

But when I open the same document using Edit from SharePoint site, the document opens in edit mode without any pop-up.

Any thoughts on why this pop up is coming, and what can be done to make this pop up go away.

The Internet suggests a cache clear of the browser but that doesn't help.

Comment: Could you try to install Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Support in Office 2016 https://helpdesk.qorusdocs.com/hc/article_attachments/203413119/003.png also check this may help https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint-mso_win10/problem-with-reopening-the-document-and-checking/2d286eae-b752-4c80-9a86-8c55596d33a2